# Error with function pointer only if the function is in a specific file

Tags: c

I'm having trouble using a function.
I have a project divided into several files, I created a function that randomly chooses the values of an enumeration.
I noticed that if I use this function in an external file it works, if I use the function in the same file clion says there is a pointer problem. All the other functions instead give me no problems, what am I doing wrong?
Here is part of the code

```
typedef enum {CORTI = 1, MEDI, LUNGHI, ALTRO} TipoCapelli; //file= struct.h

typedef struct{
  ...
 TipoCapelli tipo;
 }                                                        //end struct.h

void recordCasuale(RecordSoggetto *soggetto){             //file= rand.c
  ...
  enumRandom(&soggetto->tipo);    //Incompatible pointer types passing 'TipoCapelli*' to parameter of type 'int*'
}

void enumRandom(int* i){
int n;
n = randRange(1, 4);  //generates random number between 1 and 4
switch(n){
    case 1: *i=1; break;
    case 2: *i=2; break;
    case 3: *i=3; break;
    case 4: *i=4;
   }
}                                                        //end rand.c
```

I don't understand why if I call the enumRandom function in struct.c it doesn't give me any error.
Instead calling her in rand.c clion tells me to cast: `enumRandom((int *) &soggetto->tipo);`
What is the mistake? Why is this function only giving me the error?

Comment: What's a `TipoCapelli`?  And where are you calling `enumRandom` in rand.c?

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, smallest amount of complete code that anyone can use exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives an error because you have an error -- when you call it from another file you don't have the error.  (You didn't show us the details of that code.)

The function enum takes a `int *` as a parameter -- if you pass a different type it will give you an error.

You can fix this one of two ways

Cast the value you are passing in to the `int *`

```
 enumRandom((int *) &soggetto->tipo
```

Change the function call to use type

```
 void enumRandom(TipoCapelli* i){
```